# enable a user to chroot?

Tags: rhel, sudo, chroot, bind

I have a script that I am running as a regular user (but one that can sudo). This script relates to BIND and gathers information each time it runs. It has not been working correctly and I noticed while looking at the file it says:

"If you're running BIND in a chroot environment, use this
option to define a path to be chrooted. Please adjust also
your sudo configuration to enable the user to chroot!"

I am runnning BIND in a chroot enviroment, and I can define the path to be chrooted. However, I have no idea how to adjust the sudo config to allow the user to chroot. I know to run visudo, but after that I do not know what exactly needs to be adjusted here.

I'm running RHEL server 6.7 and BIND 9.8.2

Comment: What is the output of `sudo -l` as the user you're attempting to run the script as?

Comment: Matching Defaults entries for <user> on this host:
    always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS
    LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE",
    env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User <user> may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL

Comment: In the future, please add any updates of that length to the original question with the proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part of the output of `sudo -l` is the last line(s):

```
User <user> may run the following commands on this host: 
   (ALL) ALL
```

If what you mean by "allow the user to chroot" is "run the command `chroot`", then you already have that permission.

Comment: Ok. Just wanting to rule that out as a possible cause. I will give you the answer. Thanks!